# Make existing table work with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an independent `Google::User` and `User` the User is the normal Devise user which uses email and password to log in. I need to have a `Google::User` table for some app-specific reasons.

So now I am able to do oAuth using Google and I want to achieve the following:

- Login the user once they are authenticated
- set `Google::User` in the `current_user` variable

So I want to use the `sign_in` method to sign-in this user. Is there anything specific that my model needs? To make it compatible with Devise.

I know this has been asked before [here in the docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models) but my question is a little different as I understand.

Comment: Can't you use the normal User model for all logins (including Google users) and use the Google::User model only for your app-specific reasons (but not for login)?. Just relating both models.

Comment: Actually, that is the issue. My system allows for creating new google user via our endpoints. So I need to store that and other data like sync status etc there.